# Reading files too quickly in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
oFReader = new FileReader(), rFilter = /^(?:image\/bmp|image\/cis\-cod|image\/gif|image\/ief|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/pipeg|image\/png|image\/svg\+xml|image\/tiff|image\/x\-cmu\-raster|image\/x\-cmx|image\/x\-icon|image\/x\-portable\-anymap|image\/x\-portable\-bitmap|image\/x\-portable\-graymap|image\/x\-portable\-pixmap|image\/x\-rgb|image\/x\-xbitmap|image\/x\-xpixmap|image\/x\-xwindowdump)$/i;
oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
    $("#preview").append("<img src='" + oFREvent.target.result + "' />");
};

function loadImageFile() {
    if (document.getElementById("uploadImage").files.length === 0) { return; }

    $.each(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files, function (index, value) {
        if (!rFilter.test(value.type)) { alert("You must select a valid image file!"); return; }
        oFReader.readAsDataURL(value);
    });
}
```

It is intended to take a collection of images that have been dragged onto a input of type file, and then preview those images in a div.  My issue is that when I run this, only the last image appears.  If I add a break point into my javascript and step through the code, both images are displayed.

I am assuming that this is happening because `oFReader.onload` is being called twice very quickly.  I had considered using setTimeout or possibly declaring `oFReader` inside of my loop to try to avoid the conflict, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a separate FileReader object for each file you are reading.

`.readDataAsURL()` is an asynchronous method.  It finishes some time later after you call it.  In your `.each()` loop, you are trying to read a new file before the previous one is done, thus stopping it before it completes.

You could do something like this:

```
function loadImageFile() {
    if (document.getElementById("uploadImage").files.length === 0) { return; }

    $.each(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files, function (index, value) {
        var oFReader = new FileReader(), rFilter = /^(?:image\/bmp|image\/cis\-cod|image\/gif|image\/ief|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/pipeg|image\/png|image\/svg\+xml|image\/tiff|image\/x\-cmu\-raster|image\/x\-cmx|image\/x\-icon|image\/x\-portable\-anymap|image\/x\-portable\-bitmap|image\/x\-portable\-graymap|image\/x\-portable\-pixmap|image\/x\-rgb|image\/x\-xbitmap|image\/x\-xpixmap|image\/x\-xwindowdump)$/i;

        if (!rFilter.test(value.type)) { alert("You must select a valid image file!"); return; }
        oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
            $("#preview").append("<img src='" + oFREvent.target.result + "' />");
        };
        oFReader.readAsDataURL(value);
    });
}
```